# Turn off Konvajs warnings

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

When having more than five layers, Konva outputs a warning to the console along the lines of:

> "The stage has n layers. Recommended maximin number of layers is 3-5. Adding more layers into the stage may drop the performance. Rethink your tree structure, you can use Konva.Group."

That's good, but if everything works fine and there are no performance issues I would like to turn off the warning.

Is there a way to stop the Konva lib from outputting certain warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible: https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.html#.showWarnings

```
Konva.showWarnings = false;
```