# Can't suppress Konva warnings in Vue

Tags: konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I'm using Konva in a Vue application, and I can't suppress Konva's warnings in browser console.
According to [Konva docs, there is an option for this](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.html#.showWarnings__anchor), Konva.showWarnings = false. (I understood the warning itself and am aware of its possible implications).

I've checked this: [Turn off Konvajs warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388430/turn-off-konvajs-warnings), but to no avail, the answer here just explains that such a setting exists.

What I'm doing in my main.js file:

```
import VueKonva from 'vue-konva'
Vue.use(VueKonva)
```

and then I'm trying to apply the setting:

```
VueKonva.showWarnings = false
```

I've also tried adding it inside Vue.use as option:

```
Vue.use(VueKonva, {showWarnings: false})
```

...but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the same:

```js
import Konva from 'konva';
Konva.showWarnings = false;
```

*Are you sure you want to disable them?*

edited: as the final solution to the problem, I'm adding @lavrton's comment from below:
For the showWarnings property to work in vue-konva, you need to import both the original konva library, and the vue one for vue-bindings.

The working code now looks like this:

```js
import VueKonva from "vue-konva";
import Konva from "konva";
Konva.showWarnings = false;

Vue.use(VueKonva);
Vue.use(Konva);
```

Comment: Yes, I need to disable them temporarily as I have thousands of nodes (the warning says that id is numeric, but it should be a string - I'll get back to fixing that). But first I'll need to resolve other issues, and allowing warnings makes initial render really slow, because the browser is dealing w/ the notifications. 

I created a minimalistic example, and I can reproduce the problem here: (see console for the warnings showing up despite the Konva.showWarnings = false statement). 
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-hellman-p4c56?file=/src/main.js

Comment: @zkriszti your demo is not the same that I proposed to do.

Comment: it is a vue project, so I imported Konva as your doc states at https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/index.html - I need to import from 'vue-konva', otherwise the project will not work.

Comment: Import both. `vue-konva` for Vue bindings. And `konva` for other direct API.